# Understanding @MockMvcTest And How to Import all contexts needed

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockmvc

I have a test class using `@WebMvcTest` that looks like this

```
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest({HomeController.class, ShoppingCartController.class})
@Import({SecurityConfig.class, SecurityUtility.class, UserDetailsServiceImpl.class, UserRepository.class}) //@TestPropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class ShoppingCartControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private BookService bookService;
```

And now I'm getting a lot of unsatisfied bean dependency exceptions because `@WebMvcTest` uses slicing, My question is how can I import all the dependency without repeating `@Import` 20 times and how do I use `@MockBean`?

Previously I used

```
@AutoConfigureMockMvc

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = BookstoreApplications.class, properties = "classpath:application.properties")

public class ShoppingCartControllerTest {

    @Autowire   
   private MockMvc mockMvc     
    @Autowired

    private HomeController homeController;

    @Autowired

    private ShoppingCartController shoppingCartController;
```

And all tests were passed now I am getting a default password in the log , which means I haven't imported the Authentication Context so it used Default Authentication.

Below is the whole class as it is now

```
AutoConfigureMockMvc
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest({HomeController.class, ShoppingCartController.class})
@Import({SecurityConfig.class,UserRepository.class}) //@TestPropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class ShoppingCartControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private SecurityUtility securityUtility;

    @MockBean
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @MockBean
    private BookService bookService;

    @MockBean
    private UserService userService;

    @MockBean
    private CartItemService cartItemService;

    @Configuration
    @Import({PropertyTestConfiguration.class})
    static class ContextConfiguration {
    }


    @Test
    public void showLoginPage() throws Exception {

        mockMvc.perform(get("/login")
                .accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
        )
                .andExpect(model().attributeExists("classActiveLogin"))
                .andReturn();
    }


    @Test
    @WithMockUser(username = "V", authorities = {"USER"})
    public void addItemToShoppingCart() throws Exception {

        CartItem cartItem = new CartItem();

        String qty = "2";

        Book book = new Book();

        User user = new User();
        book.setId(1L);
        book.getId();

        cartItem.setBook(book);


        when(userService.findByUsername(anyString())).thenReturn(user);


        when(bookService.findOne(anyLong())).thenReturn(book);


        when(cartItemService.addBookToCartItem(book, user, Integer.parseInt(qty))).thenReturn(cartItem);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        String bookAsString = mapper.writeValueAsString(book);
        mockMvc
                .perform(get("/shoppingCart/addItem")
                        .accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                        .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                        .param("book", bookAsString)
                        .param("qty", qty))

                .andReturn();
    }


    @Test
    public void checkBookDetail() throws Exception {

        Book book = new Book();
        book.setId(1L);
        when(bookService.findOne(anyLong())).thenReturn(book);

        mockMvc
                .perform(get("/bookDetail")
                        .accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                        .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                        .param("id", "1"))
                .andExpect(model().attributeExists("book"))
                .andExpect(model().attributeExists("qty"))
                .andExpect(model().attributeExists("qtyList"))
                .andReturn();
    }

    @Test
    public void showBookShelf() throws Exception {
        List<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<>();

        when(bookService.findAll()).thenReturn(bookList);

        mockMvc.perform(get("/bookshelf")
                .accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
        )
                .andExpect(model().attributeExists("activeAll"))
                .andReturn();
    }

}
```

I also think its wrong to use `@Import` because I am testing two classes as I have specified in `@WebMvcTest`, every other bean should use `@MockBean`. And also I am not allowed to use `@SpringBootTest` And for some reason test addItemToShoppingCart passes while others fail